# Template argument deduction failed, trying with std::variant

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, option-type, variant

I have the following program similar with my problem. I need to get the specific class from a method like `getClass` and after that pass the object and call similar defined method. I can't use polymorphism.

```
#include <variant>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
class A{
    public:
    void foo() const {
        std::cout << "A";
    }
};


class B{
    public:
    void foo() const {
        std::cout << "B";
    }
};


class C {
    public:
    void foo() const {
        std::cout << "C";
    }
};

using Object = std::variant<A,B,C>;


std::optional<Object> getClass(int nr)
{
    if (nr == 0)
        return A{};
    else if (nr == 1)
        return B{};
    else if(nr == 2)
        return C{};
    return std::nullopt;
}

void f(const Object& ob)
{
    //how to call foo function ???
}

int main()
{
    const auto& obj = getClass(2);
    
    if (obj.has_value())
        f(obj.value());
}
```

Comment: You need to extract the `C` object from the `std::variant<A,B,C> object. You do this via `std::get<C>(ob)`, and then you can call `std::get<C>(ob).foo()`.

Comment: But how should I know inside the method ```f``` what type use in ```std::get<T>(ob)```

Comment: what template argument deduction failed? Is there a compiler error?

Comment: I got an error when I am trying to make somehting like ```template<class T> f(T ob) {ob.foo(); }```

Comment: If the question is about some code and a compiler error you should incldue both in the question. However, I think the question is clear as it is. Its just not clear what template deduction failure you refer to

Comment: I had no better idea :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

```
void f(const Object& ob)
{
    std::visit([](const auto& o){ o.foo();},ob);
}
```

Comment: Most likely will want to use `auto& o`, so that it doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Great thanks a lot